# September 2009 CC Wiki data dump's name is wrong.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-dump

September 2009 CC Wiki data dump uses August as the month in the file name: `so-export-2009-08.7z`. This is the same as last month's data dump.

Maybe someone forgot to increment the file name?  Or someone thought the data dump should be named for the month it is effective (last day of August.)  Either way, there is now a naming conflict with older dumps.

Comment: Wow...I was not really paying attention there...thanks Rich B.  (Do people ever thank you?  Or is it all just blow back?)

Comment: @Stu: Just wait, some troll will be by shortly to tell me how I have changed the meaning and tone of your post. Don't worry, I am numb to it all. Thanks for the acknowledgement though.

Comment: According to the history on this, "Rich B" edited out a waffles comment. Clearly his account has been hacked.

Comment: No he didn't edit out a waffles comment, he edited out a **waffels** comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will own this - there's still a few manual steps in this process which I will be automating.

We've decided to name the file from this point on with the month it is effective.

October will be named **so-export-2009-09.7z** as it includes all data up to and including September 30th 2009.

Comment: So this is now status-bydesign. Aren't you clever.

Comment: That works for me.  And makes more sense.

Comment: *It's a feature!*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, Geoff set up the filename. It's written in stone at this point, so .. closing.